# I am not getting any output in my node.js code how do I edit it?

Tags: node.js, express

I've been doin this BMI Calculator where I enter 2 numbers and these 2 numbers are calculated in my server and the answer is displayed but I do not receive output when I click submit. Can someone please show me how to submit the form?

my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>BMI calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2">
    <input type="button" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my js code

```
let express = require("express")
let bodyParser = require("body-parser")
let app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("working")
})
app.get('/',function(request,respond){
    respond.sendFile(__dirname+"/bmiCalculator.html")
})
app.post('/',function(req,res){
    let num1 = Number(req.body.num1)
    let num2 = Number(req.body.num2)
    let result = num1/num2*num2
res.send(result)
})
```

Comment: Change `<input type="button" value="submit">` to `<input type="submit" value="submit">`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i also noticed that after I click the submit button I am getting a list of my files in index C but not my required answer. Can u pls help me w that also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under form, `change submit input statement`

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="userInput" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i also noticed that after I click the submit button I am getting a list of my files in index C but not my required answer. Can u pls help me w that also?

Comment: Is that another question? and can you post that files? and if this answer helped you, please accept it as a solution to your answer so that it may help others in the future :)

Comment: please accept this as your answer if it worked, for future reference